# Laravel socialite- route not found

Tags: facebook, laravel, twitter, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have followed this tutorial:

https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.WTFGLGg1_IU
and
https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-twitter-login.html#.WTFGPmg1_IX

And I have completed both tutorials. However after trying to log in using either facebook or twitter I get "NotfoundHttpException"

The code is the same as on these tutorial but just for the sake of it I will post it here all in one:

This is using Socialize package:

SocialAuthController.php:

```
class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect($provider)
    {
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();    
    } 
public function callback(SocialAccountService $service, $provider)
{
    // Important change from previous post is that I'm now passing
    // whole driver, not only the user. So no more ->user() part
    $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver($provider));

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect()->to('/tfgm');
}
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/redirect/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@callback');
```

SocialAccountService.php ( I put this inside app folder where models are, i don't know if that is correct):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Provider;

class SocialAccountService
{
    public function createOrGetUser(Provider $provider)
    {

        $providerUser = $provider->user();
        $providerName = class_basename($provider); 

        $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider($providerName)
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => $providerName
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {

                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;

        }

    }
}
```